# Цвет кнопки при наведении, отличный от класса в css

Tags: html, css

Через css заданы стили при наведении на кнопку:

```css
    .mybtn{
     text-align: center; 
     padding: 8px 10px; 
     border: solid 1px #777777; 
     color: #7777777; 
     background:#ffffff;
     tansition: all .3s linear;
     -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
     -moz-transition: all .3s linear;  
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .mybtn:hover {
     color: #fff;
     background: #333;
     tansition: all .3s linear;
     -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
     -moz-transition: all .3s linear; 
    }
```

```html
<button class="mybtn">button1</button>
<button class="mybtn">button2</button>
<button class="mybtn">button3</button>
```

Размещаю 3 кнопки на одной странице.
Вопрос такой:

Мне необходимо, чтобы при наведении на кнопки, у каждой был разный `background`.
По коду видно, что при наведении, фон меняется с белого на черный.
Нужно, чтобы при наведении на:

- кнопку 1 менялся на синий
- кнопку 2 менялся на красный
- кнопку 3 менялся на зелёный

Comment: Добавьте ещо один клас к кнопка и уже ему дайте стили

Answer (score 1):

без разметки могу предложить лишь **[nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)**

```css
  .mybtn{
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 8px 10px; 
    border: solid 1px #777777; 
    color: #7777777; 
    background:#ffffff;
    tansition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mybtn:hover {
    color: #fff;    
    tansition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear; 
}

.mybtn:nth-child(1):hover { 
  background: blue;
}

.mybtn:nth-child(2):hover { 
  background: red;
}

.mybtn:nth-child(3):hover { 
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="mybtn" />
<input type="button" class="mybtn" />
<input type="button" class="mybtn" />
```

Comment: задача в том что у меня более 200 различных цветов. В вопросе написал про три.

Comment: @RusBolik значит 1) надо было задачу полностью описывать)) 2) тут значит скорее всего нужен js

Comment: Алексей, может подскажите. Я в js скриптах полный ноль

Comment: @RusBolik тут зависит всё от исходных данных. что это за кнопки, откуда берутся, генерируются ли через PHP или это статичная разметка, какова в целом задача и пр. Чтобы посоветовать нужно больше входных данных.  Например если генерируются кнопки, то самый простой вариант - писать атрибут `data` к ним с прикрепленным к ним цветом и уже при наведении брать оттуда цвет. Будет некий модифицированный вариант вот такого плана: https://jsfiddle.net/ohk18qda/  ......... но без полного конкретного описания сказать нельзя. Ну и т.к. это будет другой вопрос по js - придется задавать его снова))

Answer (score 0):

Алексей Шиманский, спасибо за поддержку.
Я решил вопрос таким путем, вычитанном на буржуинском форуме.
И потом уже в самой ссылке прописываю нужный цвет через style="background-color: #нужный цвет;"

```css
.mybtn{
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 8px 10px; 
 border: solid 1px #777777; 
 color: #7777777; 
 background:#ffffff;
 tansition: all .3s linear;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .3s linear;  
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mybtn:not(:hover){
 color: #000;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
.mybtn:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #333;
 tansition: all .3s linear;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .3s linear; 
  }
  .mybtn:active{
  color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<p><a href="#" class="mybtn">Обычная</a></p>
<p><a href="#" style="background:#0000ff;" class="mybtn">Синяя</a></p>
<p><a href="#" style="background:#808080;" class="mybtn">Серая</a></p>
```